# Calculate how many points a route goes through

Tags: point, routing, software-recommendations, proximity

Is there a way in which a route mapping interface can determine how many points a certain (user created) route has 'touched'?

In the sense that firstly:

1. I have a set of markers or points (e.g. geojson format)
2. I have a route from A to B.
3. How many of these pre-determined points does route A to B go through?

Even if a route does not exactly go through a point (i.e. is which a certain radius of the point), is here any software or programme that can perform this function? And, if any, is there a web-facing interface that can do this?

Comment: For candidate software I think you should look on our site for questions tagged [tag:proximity] or [tag:buffer] because you are really just looking to select and count points within a small distance of a line.  From there it should be possible to ask a more focussed question.

Answer (score 1):

If you can load the point data into PostGIS, you can run a query to find the answer:

```sql
SELECT name 
FROM points 
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[0,0],[1,1]]}'), 1);
```

This will return the `NAME` of each point that falls within `1` unit of measurement from the line between `0,0` and `1,1`.

And if you just want the count, then you can change the first line to `SELECT count(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you have predefined points like POIs and now you need to find out if a route is near these POIs?

This is easily doable with the open source routing engine [GraphHopper](https://graphhopper.com/) (note: I'm the author):

- Run routing algorithm from A to B
- Start a Dijkstra from all the nodes of the route until a certain distance or time is reached (satisfying your 'near' definition) and see if the POI nodes or edges are touched